# how to connect to mysql using jsp

Tags: server

```
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    //ResultSet rs;
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(first_name,last_name,email,uname, pass, regdate) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email +"','" + user + "','" + pwd + "', CURDATE())");
     if (i > 0) 
    {
   //session.setAttribute("userid", user);
   //response.sendRedirect("userList2.jsp");
  out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='userList2.jsp'>View Members</a>");
 }
```

Comment: i have use with tomcat but it cannot connect because The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: First as Ivanhercaz suggested, please read that guide. Please use the appropriate tags and write a description of your problem. Also you haven't mentioned your question exactly.